# Array of structs with multiple members

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

In struct "saf" i have the array "stack" and in struct "data" i have "pinx" which is the array of struct "data" . I want to the array "stack" to have as members the "pinx" array, but i don't know how can i have access from stack array to the members of pinx. I provide you an image so you will understand what i want to do.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct saf
{
  int head;
  void **stack;
  int size;
}exp1;

struct data
{
  int flag;
  char name[50];
};

 struct data *pinx;

void init(int n)
{

  pinx = malloc(sizeof(struct data) * n);
  exp1.stack = malloc(n);

}

void add()
{

 strcpy(pinx[0].name,"name");
 pinx[0].flag=0;
 exp1.stack[0]=&pinx[0];

}

int main()
{

 printf("Give size: ");
 scanf("%d",&exp1.size);
 init(exp1.size);
 add();

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `exp1.stack = malloc(n);` is probably an error, I think you meant `exp1.stack = malloc(n * sizeof *exp1.stack)`, which will let you have `n` pointers in that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
void *stack;
```

in your `saf` struct.

```
exp1.stack = malloc(n); //is not needed
```

Then

```
exp1.stack = (void *)pinx;
```

and accessing elements

```
printf("%s \n", ((struct data *)exp1.stack)[0].name);
```

valter

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need a cast:

```
struct data* getElement(struct saf* from, int i)
{
    void* vp = from->stack[i];
    struct data* d = (struct data*)(vp);
    return vp;
}
```

So you can then write:

```
void checkGet()
{
    struct data* e1 = getElement(&exp1, 0);
    printf("%d %s\n", e1->flag, e1->name);
}
```

Of course, some error checking would be good - the accessor should check `i` is in range and probably return `0` if not.

Comment: This is not what i want. I need something like that : For example i need to print the flag from the second element of stack which is pinx[1].flag , exp1.stack->pinx[1]->flag (-> not pointer only just an arrow so i can make you understand what i want)

Comment: To get the second element, call `getElement(exp1, 1)`? Not sure what else you could want.

Comment: i want to use stack array only. I want to have access to flag and name through stack , like this : exp1.stack[i]=pinx[i] and from there to gain access to the members of pinx